# How can I make sure that an NSArray is always sorted, using ReactiveCocoa?

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Let's say that I have a ColorListViewModel whose model is an array of Color objects:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *colors;
```

and I update the entire model when a command is executed:

```
RAC(self, colors) = [_fetchColorsCommand.executionSignals flatten];
```

while also having an `addColor:` method which does the following:

```
- (void)addColor:(Color *)color
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableColors = [self.colors mutablecopy];
    [mutableColors addObject:color];
    self.colors = [mutableColors copy];
}
```

I could sort the array of colors (by name, for example) in multiple places using NSSortDescriptor.

How can I subscribe to changes to `self.colors` and perform the sorting there? So far my attempts to do this have resulted in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it depends on if you do more inserting or more reading...

if you do a lot of inserting and not a lot of reading, then you could sort lazily...
both of these examples require you to define `-(NSComparisonResult)compareColor:(id)someOtherColor`...
you could also use a block or function.

```
- (NSArray *)colors
{
   return [_colors sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareColor:) ];
}
```

or you could sort up front on insert, if you read more frequently

```
- (void)addColor:(Color *)color
{
    NSMutableArray *mutableColors = [self.colors mutablecopy];
    [mutableColors addObject:color];
    self.colors = [mutableColors sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareColor:)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `distinctUntilChanged` was what I was missing to prevent the infinite loop.

```
[[RACObserve(self, colors) distinctUntilChanged] subscribeNext:^(NSArray *colors) {
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    self.colors = [colors sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
}];
```

This appears to be working although I'm not aware of any caveats at this point.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19673276/339925) it's not a good idea to bind to the same property multiple times.

This is why my answer written as `RAC(self, colors) = [[RACObserve(self, colors) distinctUntilChanged] map:...` doesn't work.