# Rac signal is already bound to key path

Tags: ios, signals, reactive-cocoa, subscribe

I'm trying to subscribe the signal,but while the cell reuse,there will cause exception "Signal  name:  is already bound to key path "nickname" on object , adding signal  name:  is undefined behavior"

here is the code

```
 RACSignal *_sn = [[cell.functionTextField.rac_textSignal takeUntil:cell.rac_prepareForReuseSignal] map:^(NSString *value) {
                    if ([value length] > 9) {
                        return [value substringToIndex:9];
                    } else {
                        return value;
                    }
                }];

  RAC(cell.functionTextField, text) = _sn;
  RAC(_hp,nickname) = _sn;
```

How do i fix that?

Comment: Where are you using this code? In table view data source?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (RACDisposable *)setKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath onObject:(NSObject *)object nilValue:(id)nilValue
```

the assert raised by above method [RACSignal+Operations.m] in debug model.
avoid binding a signal twice is good habit.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650802/remove-a-reactivecocoa-signal-from-a-control

Answer (score 0):

In my case this occurred because I doing two things simultaneously which caused a conflict:

1)  Setting an RACCommand to the `.rac_command` on a `UIButton` with `allowsConcurrentExecution = YES` that kicks off a network request;

2) And ... I was setting the `enabled` property of a `UIButton` to "not executing:

`RAC(viewallButton, enabled) = [command.executing not];`

Apparently, `allowsConcurrentExecution = NO` already takes care of disabling the button while the signal is still executing a network request, and when I added this code to disable the button, it was binding it twice, thereby causing the conflict.